# What data format is buffer?

Tags: javascript, sql, json, node.js, blob

I am creating an application using Nodejs. The image is stored as blobs in SQL. After I fetch the image from SQL, I checked to see the format it is in. The JSON response of the image appears like this.

[image: Response after fetching the image]

After I send the data to the front end, the image appears in this format

[image: JSON Response in the front end]

Since it displays Buffer, I am confused what the image format is. What format is the image in?

Comment: `Buffer` is basically just a binary blob.  You will have to evaluate that binary data to determine what image format it is (or use a 3rd party module that does the same)

Comment: @Joe Thanks! So, if I were to display it on the UI, what format am I supposed to convert it into?

Answer (score 1):

The format is JPEG ([JFIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure)). If you take a look at

```
(255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 200)
```

or equivalently:

```
FF D8 FF E0  00 10 4A 46        .......J
49 46 00 01  01 01 00 C8        FIF.....
```

especially `4A 46 49 46 00`, this is the identifier `JFIF`.

```
FF D8           # Start of Image

FF E0           # APP0 marker
00 10           # length of segment:  16 bytes
4A 46 49 46 00  # "JFIF\0"
01 01           # version:            1.01
01              # pixel density unit: pixels per inch
00 CB           # Xdensity:           200 ppi
...
```